# Application crashing due to unicode characters in string

Tags: string, cocoa, unicode, nsstring, utf-16

I am making an application in which I have to store data from remote db into local sqlite3 db.

> Problem is - when any string to be
>   inserted contains unicode character
>   such as: \U00a0 or \U2022 or \U2019,
>   it crashes.

The part of code which crashes is this-

```
NSString *insertQuery = @"insert into XYZ(field1,field2) values (@"1",[recordDict objectForKey:@"field2"]);

// recordDict contains value: @"\U00a0 \U00a0 \U00a0 \U00a0The Cadfsdfsdfptain\U2019s" for key: @"field2"

sqlite3_stmt *insertStmnt;
const char *sql = [insertQuery cStringUsingEncoding:1];

printf("insertQuery - %s",sql); // it is showing insertQuery - (null) and crashing at next line
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &insertStmnt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
    NSLog(@"Error while creating insert statement. '%s'",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this problem?

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cStringUsingEncoding:` returns `NULL` when the string cannot be losslessly converted to the specified encoding, hence your crash. You can use `canBeConvertedToEncoding:` to ensure the conversion is possible.

Furthermore, the value `1` corresponds to `NSASCIIStringEncoding` which will certainly fail for a string with Unicode characters. `NSUTF8StringEncoding` might be more appropriate.